# Python code for finding the 1001st prime number

Tags: python, primes

I recently started programming Python and was stuck at this particular Project Euler problem for finding the 1001st prime number.
My code:

```
L = [2]
def is_prime(x,L):
    for el in L:
        if x%el != 0:
            flag = 1
        else:
            flag = 0
            break    
    if flag == 1:
        return True
    elif flag == 0:
        return False

a = 3
for k in range(1,1002):
    if is_prime(a,L) is True:
        L.append(a)
        a += 1
        k += 1
    else:
        a += 1
print(L)
print(len(L))
```

This prints the list of prime numbers upto 997 which is the 168th prime number. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hint:  You have a `range()` statement for `k` *and* you are incrementing `k`.

Comment: The problem is that the `for` loop takes in iterable and enumerates that, the `k += 1` has no effect (nor has `k -= 1` effect).

Comment: Thank you! I was too focused on my is_prime function & just overlooked that. That was silly of me, thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: consider using while(True): ... if len(L)>1000: break. So you don't need to keep care of a counter and directly check the size of the output. Better style.

Comment: Reading a+=1 both inside the if **and** inside the else hurts my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Your increment of `k` is pointless, because you're iterating a fixed range of numbers (`k` is replaced when the loop loops, the `range` can't be changed dynamically).

You want a `while` loop with a manually managed `k`:

```
a = 3
k = 1
while k < 1002:
    if is_prime(a,L):
        L.append(a)
        a += 1
        k += 1
    else:
        a += 1
```

Note: There may be some off-by-one logic errors here, but it expresses what I assume was your intent in the original code, fixing only the issue with managing `k`.

Comment: That was the mistake i was making! Thank you very much. And yeah I'd have to change my k's limit to 1000 to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

k += 1

That's where the problem is. Try this code:

```
for k in range(1, 1002):
    print(k)
```

and then:

```
for k in range(1, 1002):
    k += 1
    print(k)
```

Comment: Thank you! This really pin-pointed my mistake. Ran both these codes and found out where the problem was.

Comment: @niedzwiedzwo It still won't help you find the 1001st prime number though... you'll need to do something else to handle that.  This is only searching 1 through 1001 to see if a number is prime, which is a slightly different problem. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Your Mistake is that you are finding numbers that are prime UP to 1001 and Also variables of a loop cannot increase By the user
to fix that use a while loop

Answer (score -2):

A Program To Find Up Prime's To Any Number would be:

```
import sys
def prime_num_finder():
    i = 2
    while True:
        try:
            p = int(input("Please enter up to what number the prime numbers should be: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            sys.stderr.write('ERROR\n')
            sys.stderr.write(' Try again...\n')
    while  i != (p + 1):
        x = i

        if x % 2 and  x % 3 and x % 5 and x % 7 > 0.1: # Checks if the remainder is greater than 0.1 to see if it has an remainder
            r1 = True

        else:
            if i == 2 or i == 3 or i == 5 or i == 7:
                r1 = True        
            else:
                r1 = False
        if r1 == True:
            print(i, " is a prime number!")
        else:
            pass
        i = i + 1

prime_num_finder()
quit()
```

That is a simple program to check if it is divisible by 2 ,3, 5, or 7

Comment: Writing a completely independent solution (that has all sorts of non-idiomatic constructs as well as utterly wrong) isn't really the point here. Help them find the problem with their code, don't just write completely different code.